# Named arguments call in C# with variable parameter number

Tags: c#, function, parameters

Suppose I have the following C# function:

```
void Foo(int bar, params string[] parpar) { }
```

I want to call this function using named arguments:

```
Foo(bar: 5, parpar: "a", "b", "c");
```

The compiler gives error message: “Named arguments cannot precede positional” since I have no name before “b” and “c”.

Is there any way to use named arguments without manually representing params as an array?

Comment: Did you try with `Foo(5, "a", "b", "c");` ?

Comment: `Foo(bar: 5, parpar: stringArray);` where `var stringArray = new string[]{"a", "b", "c"})` or `Foo(bar: 5, parpar: new string[]{"a", "b", "c"})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no syntactic sugar to make variable arguments named  except explicitly specifying array.

Note that `params` arguments would need to be individually named if such syntax would be allowed (to see where positioned argument ends), but there is only one name.

Answer (score 7):

Adding this in case someone lands here from google like I did.  You will also receive this error when you have not explicitly named all your parameters and all your explictly named parameters are not at the end.

```
void Foo( int parameterOne, int parameterTwo, int parameterThree) {};

// throws Named Arguments cannot precede positional
Foo(parameterOne: 1, parameterTwo:2, 3);

//This is okay
Foo(1, parameterTwo:2, parameterThree:3);
```